# How to get the angle formed by an hexagon which has two lines on it?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

The problem is as follows:

> In a regular hexagon $ABCDEF$ a point $G$ is located on $CD$ such that
> $AG$ and $BE$ intersect at point $R$. If $\angle AGD = 110^\circ$.
> Find $\angle BCR$.

The alternatives given in my book are:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&40^\circ\\
2.&35^\circ\\
3.&50^\circ\\
4.&45^\circ\\
\end{array}$

I'm stuck on this problem. However since this problem does not include a graph. I did my best effort as an interpretation of what has been mentioned.

And I believe the problem is indicating this figure:

[image: Sketch of the problem]

But what to do from here?. I cannot spot which sort of theorem or identity relying on **euclidean geometry approach** could be used to solve this problem?.

Can someone help me here?. I've attempted to look for congruence or maybe construction but I just can't spot else. Please include a drawing in your answer. Please help.

Comment: Why is it that you've accepted almost-no answers to your questions over the years?

Comment: @Blue I'm sorry for that. I'm doing my best to keep up to date, it is not easy to review and understand all the answers. I have to do that to take a good judgement and also my health isn't very good so I cannot use internet connection too often. But I'll take note to improve that.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is 50 degrees.

First, construct a straight line from C to R. Then, label the point at which this meets AF as $G'$.

Recall that in a regular hexagon, the internal angles are $120^\circ$. This implies that $\angle AFE=120^\circ$, and $\angle BEF=60^\circ$.

Also, note that the lines CG' and AG are "reflections" of each other across the line BE. Thus, $\angle CG'F=\angle AGD=110^\circ$ by symmetry. Note that G'REF is a quadrilateral, which has an internal angle sum of $360 ^\circ$. Hence, we conclude that $\angle G'RE=360^\circ-120^\circ-60^\circ=70^\circ$. This of course means that $\angle BRC=\angle G'RE=70^\circ$, due to vertically opposite angles being equal.  Note that $\angle RBC =60 ^\circ$. From these, we can conclude that $\angle BCR=50^\circ$ since the angles of the triangle BCR add up to $180 ^\circ$.

Comment: I think you need to correct $\angle RG'F =360-(120+110+60)=70^\circ$ and also note that $\angle G'RE=\angle BRC$ then $\angle RBC=60^\circ$ ,therefore in $\triangle CBR$ you use the identity that all angles add up to $180^\circ$ and because of such $\angle BCR=50^\circ$ for that the rest I think its okay. Would you mind to include these corrections? as part of your answer?.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell You're right, it seems that I have made a typo where I accidentally wrote $\angle RG'F=360-....=70 ^\circ$ when it should've been $\angle G'RE$ instead.

Comment: I will also add some more lines for further clarification, thanks!